# How to insert a new value at certain index in an array and shift everything down by one index?

Tags: arrays, vba

let's say if I have this array in vba

```
a(0) = 1
a(1) = f
a(2) = g
a(3) = 4
.
..
..
a(k) = a
```

and I want to insert a new value at (0) and shift every value down by one index like this

```
a(0) = newVal
a(1) = 1
a(2) = f
a(3) = g
a(4) = 4
.
..
..
a(k+1) = a
```

is there a short hand code to do this if not what's the fastest way to do this?

I can do this with simple for loop but I was wondering if there is more efficient way?

Example this is what I can come up with

```
Dim temp()

Redim Preserve temp(0)
temp(0) = "newVal"

For i= lbound(a) + 1 to ubound(a) + 1
     redim preserve temp(i)
     temp(i) = a(i-1)
Next i
```

Comment: come on, you've been here long enough, you know how it works, what have you tried so far ? share your code attempt

Comment: Nah, you'd have to loop! ;) You could do this a in a procedure so that it is easily reused, but you'll have to transfer each values of the array! Post your code and poke if you're stuck! ;) @ShaiRado : Morning beautiful!^^

Comment: If you know ahead of time you'll have to do something like this, you should use a Collection instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't mind having all string values at the end

```
Dim newVal As Variant
Dim tempVar As Variant

newVal = "newValue"

tempVar = newVal & "|"  & Join(a, "|")
ReDim a(0 To k + 1) As Variant
tempVar = Split(tempVar, "|")
For i = 0 To k + 1
    a(i) = tempVar(i)
Next
```

Answer (score 3):

The code below will add a value (through variable `NewVal`) to an existing populated array. You can use the code to add an element in the middle of the array or the end (if you need to), you just need to modify the value of `ElemId`.

**Note**: If you are reading the array `a` values from a worksheet's range, then the code can be simplified.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddElemToArray()

Dim a() As Variant
Dim ElemId  As Long, i As Long
Dim NewVal As Variant

ReDim a(0 To 4) '<-- modify th value 4 to your array size
NewVal = "Test"

a(0) = 1
a(1) = "f"
a(2) = "g"
a(3) = 4
a(4) = "a"

ReDim Preserve a(0 To UBound(a) + 1)

ElemId = 2 '<-- which element ID inside the array to modify

For i = UBound(a) To ElemId + 1 Step -1
    a(i) = a(i - 1)
Next i
a(ElemId) = NewVal

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Generalizing [@Shai Rado's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42340206/2902367), here is the `ReDim` approach as a general reusable function.
Parameter `index` is optional; if omitted, the new item will be added to the end (like `push`)

```
Function ArrayInsert(ByRef a As Variant, NewVal As Variant, Optional index As Integer = -1) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim Preserve a(0 To UBound(a) + 1)
    If index = -1 Then index = UBound(a)
    For i = UBound(a) To index + 1 Step -1
        a(i) = a(i - 1)
    Next i
    a(index) = NewVal
    ArrayInsert = a
End Function
```

for convenience, this mutates the input array `a` as well as returning the mutated array.

Answer (score 1):

```
Public Function InsertFrontArray(InputArr As Variant, value As Variant) As Variant

InsertFrontArray = Split(value & "|" & Join(InputArr, "|"), "|")

End Function
```